# Woocommerce set billing and shipping information

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Update - short version:**

What method would be used to save the user billing/shipping information to session for a guest checkout?

---

Long version:

Creating a custom checkout page relying heavily on custom REST API endpoints and ajax. I have all the billing and shipping fields from `WC()->checkout()->checkout_fields;` coming back from one call, rendering it out to the user and all that.

I also have the calculated shipping cost coming back through an API call. However, that only works when the user's address is set - which is expected.

What I cannot for the life of me figure out is what method I can call in an API to save the user billing and shipping information so that I can calculate that shipping cost. Right now I can only get the shipping information on an existing user account. Even just a finger in the right direction here would save what hair I have left.

---

**Some code**

How I'm getting shipping (Doesn't work without shipping address, can't figure out how to set billing or shipping information)

```
function mytheme_get_shipping(){
    foreach( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $method_id => $rate ){
        if( WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0] == $method_id ){
            $rate_label = $rate->label; // The shipping method label name
            $rate_cost_excl_tax = floatval($rate->cost); // The cost excluding tax
            // The taxes cost
            $rate_taxes = 0;
            foreach ($rate->taxes as $rate_tax)
                $rate_taxes += floatval($rate_tax);
            // The cost including tax
            $rate_cost_incl_tax = $rate_cost_excl_tax + $rate_taxes;

            return array('label' => $rate_label, 'total' => WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you unable to get billing & shipping information when someone checkout as 'guest'? Can you post your full code here - including 'hook' in which you are calling custom API?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress no, I'm unable to SET the billing and shipping information period. That's what I'm trying to figure out. No hooks - built the entire thing as a single-page app with rest api endpoints to add/remove/update cart items, etc. I need to create a rest api endpoint where I can pass in the billing/shipping info to save it - but I don't know what method to call inside that to get them into the session.

Comment: Are you calling the API in realtime when someone placing an order?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress that's my plan... looks like I may just have to post the billing/shipping information and that it's not stored in session?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Getting Billing & Shipping Details:

You can get billing and shipping details as given below.

```
//whole customer details
print_r(WC()->customer);

//billing details
$billing = WC()->customer->get_billing(); 
$billing_first_name = WC()->customer->get_billing_first_name(); 
$billing_last_name = WC()->customer->get_billing_last_name(); 
$billing_company = WC()->customer->get_billing_company(); 
$billing_address = WC()->customer->get_billing_address(); 
$billing_address_1 = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_1(); 
$billing_address_2 = WC()->customer->get_billing_address_2(); 
$billing_city = WC()->customer->get_billing_city(); 
$billing_state = WC()->customer->get_billing_state(); 
$billing_postcode = WC()->customer->get_billing_postcode(); 
$billing_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country(); 

//shipping details
$shipping = WC()->customer->get_shipping(); 
$shipping_first_name = WC()->customer->get_shipping_first_name(); 
$shipping_last_name = WC()->customer->get_shipping_last_name(); 
$shipping_company = WC()->customer->get_shipping_company(); 
$shipping_address = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address(); 
$shipping_address_1 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_1(); 
$shipping_address_2 = WC()->customer->get_shipping_address_2(); 
$shipping_city = WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(); 
$shipping_state = WC()->customer->get_shipping_state(); 
$shipping_postcode = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode(); 
$shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
```

> Setting Billing & Shipping Details:

You can set billing and shipping details as given below.

```
//billing details
$billing_first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
$billing_last_name = $_POST['billing_last_name'];
$billing_company = $_POST['billing_company'];
$billing_address_1 = $_POST['billing_address_1'];
$billing_address_2 = $_POST['billing_address_2'];
$billing_city = $_POST['billing_city'];
$billing_state = $_POST['billing_state'];
$billing_postcode = $_POST['billing_postcode'];
$billing_country = $_POST['billing_country'];

WC()->customer->set_billing_first_name(wc_clean( $billing_first_name )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_last_name(wc_clean( $billing_last_name )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_company(wc_clean( $billing_company ));  
WC()->customer->set_billing_address_1(wc_clean( $billing_address_1 )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_address_2(wc_clean( $billing_address_2 )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_city(wc_clean( $billing_city )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_state(wc_clean( $billing_state )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_postcode(wc_clean( $billing_postcode )); 
WC()->customer->set_billing_country(wc_clean( $billing_country )); 

//shipping details
$shipping_first_name = $_POST['shipping_first_name'];
$shipping_last_name = $_POST['shipping_last_name'];
$shipping_company = $_POST['shipping_company'];
$shipping_address_1 = $_POST['shipping_address_1'];
$shipping_address_2 = $_POST['shipping_address_2'];
$shipping_city = $_POST['shipping_city'];
$shipping_state = $_POST['shipping_state'];
$shipping_postcode = $_POST['shipping_postcode'];
$shipping_country = $_POST['shipping_country'];

WC()->customer->set_shipping_first_name(wc_clean( $shipping_first_name )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_last_name(wc_clean( $shipping_last_name )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_company(wc_clean( $shipping_company ));    
WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_1(wc_clean( $shipping_address_1 )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_address_2(wc_clean( $shipping_address_2 )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_city(wc_clean( $shipping_city )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_state(wc_clean( $shipping_state )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_postcode(wc_clean( $shipping_postcode )); 
WC()->customer->set_shipping_country(wc_clean( $shipping_country ));
```

> Create New Customer and Set Billing & Shipping Details:

You can create new customer, set billing and shipping details as given below.

```
//create new customer
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$user_id = wc_create_new_customer( $email, $username, $password );

//billing details
$billing_first_name = $_POST['billing_first_name'];
$billing_last_name = $_POST['billing_last_name'];
$billing_company = $_POST['billing_company'];
$billing_address_1 = $_POST['billing_address_1'];
$billing_address_2 = $_POST['billing_address_2'];
$billing_city = $_POST['billing_city'];
$billing_state = $_POST['billing_state'];
$billing_postcode = $_POST['billing_postcode'];
$billing_country = $_POST['billing_country'];

update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_first_name", $billing_first_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_last_name", $billing_last_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_company", $billing_company );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_address_1", $billing_address_1 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_address_2", $billing_address_2 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_city", $billing_city );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_state", $billing_state );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_postcode", $billing_postcode );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "billing_country", $billing_country );

//shipping details
$shipping_first_name = $_POST['shipping_first_name'];
$shipping_last_name = $_POST['shipping_last_name'];
$shipping_company = $_POST['shipping_company'];
$shipping_address_1 = $_POST['shipping_address_1'];
$shipping_address_2 = $_POST['shipping_address_2'];
$shipping_city = $_POST['shipping_city'];
$shipping_state = $_POST['shipping_state'];
$shipping_postcode = $_POST['shipping_postcode'];
$shipping_country = $_POST['shipping_country'];

update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_first_name", $shipping_first_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_last_name", $shipping_last_name );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_company", $shipping_company );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_address_1", $shipping_address_1 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_address_2", $shipping_address_2 );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_city", $shipping_city );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_state", $shipping_state );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_postcode", $shipping_postcode );
update_user_meta( $user_id, "shipping_country", $shipping_country );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How. Do. I. Set. Them. In. The. First. Place?

Comment: You can retrieve these data only in checkout page for guests. Do you just want to set these initially? Can you able to use WooCommerce hooks?

Comment: I don't have a "Checkout page" - I have a single-page application that uses custom API endpoints to handle adding/removing data and updating the UI. I have the form. I just need to save the entered data to the session in my API function somewhere. I did find `WC()->checkout->process_checkout()`, which with some modification will take the posted and posted billing/shipping/payment data and process checkout, but I'd still like to have the information correctly saved to session

Comment: You can *set* billing & shipping details in the same way. Can you try my second part of the answer and let me know whether it helps?

Comment: You can try the third part if customer not created previously.

Comment: I will try this shortly. This will set the fields for non-registered (guest) user?

Comment: Yes, but the third part will create a customer and then set the billing & shipping details. Try the second part and let me know.